# HDinsight hive output to blob

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

I am using Hive on HDinsight, and I want to store the output of the job in Azure storage (blob). I tried

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 'wasb://mycontainer@myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/'

SELECT name, COUNT(*) as count FROM test
  GROUP BY name
  ORDER BY count DESC
```

But this returned error "Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object". Can you please help me redirect the output of the job to Azure blob storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To point to Azure Blob Storage, you need to use the `wasb://` or `wasbs://` uri prefix, like:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 'wasb://mycontainer@myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/output' ...
```

This article has lots of examples: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage/

I think you also need to provide a directory in the path.  It looks like INSERT OVERWRITE expects to be able to operate on the directory in a way that is not allowed at the root.  Can you try:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 'wasb://mycontainer@myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/output'

SELECT name, COUNT(*) as count FROM test
  GROUP BY name
  ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Also, don't forget to terminate the expression with the ;

Lastly, if the above does not work, can you confirm that you have access to the storage account in question from the Hive session by just running:

```
dfs -ls wasb://mycontainer@myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/;
```

Comment: aah! Sorry. Yes -- I used the wasb://.... in the URI. (edited my post now). I got the error even after using wasb://...

Comment: Can you provide more of your script?  Usually after the directory path you'll have a SELECT query that defines the data that you want to output to that location.  See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Writingdataintothefilesystemfromqueries for full syntax.

Comment: I edited my original post with the SELECT part of the query. Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear! Please mark as answered if this is all you needed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by RickH before, you were missing two things - a directory under the container name and a semi-comma after the SELECT statement. The following code should work.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 'wasb://mycontainer@myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/2'

SELECT name, COUNT(*) as count FROM test
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY count DESC;
```